# Is it possible to use AT&T 3G on a Verizon LTE iPad?

Tags: cellular-carriers, ipad, lte, cellular-data

According to [the new iPad tech specs page](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/), in addition to their separate LTE bands, both the Verizon and AT&T models ship with:

> - UMTS/HSPA/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz);
> - GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)

So it's clear that the Verizon LTE iPad has the radios and the bands to use AT&T's 3G network. It even has a micro-SIM tray. Would it be possible to get an AT&T micro-SIM and use AT&T 3G on a Verizon LTE iPad?

For me, this would be the best of both worlds. I don't live in an area with LTE yet, but given the rollout pace from Verizon and AT&T it's very likely that Verizon will get to my area long before AT&T will. However, currently, I get pretty good AT&T 3G coverage on my iPhone, and it's significantly faster than Verizon's network. So my idea is to get the Verizon iPad but use the AT&T 3G if I can, until I get Verizon LTE coverage in my area (or I visit an area with Verizon LTE).

Would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't the only person that's been interested in this. There's an article on [MacRumors](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/03/16/new-verizon-ipad-runs-on-att-3g-networks-with-att-micro-sim/) that states that this is indeed possible, which is good news for me. The person that discovered it wrote:

> Big question on everyone's mind buying the Verizon iPad was whether data from AT&Ts 3G network would work on this iPad, or if Verizon/Apple would block this.
>
> I was one of the first to obtain a Verizon iPad and can happily confirm that this is allowed! I used my ATT iPhone 4S sim card and took out the Verizon sim, and data worked! You must apply the AT&T APN carrier settings before this works though.
>
> BTW APN carrier settings can be changed here: [unlockit.co.nz](http://unlockit.co.nz)

**edit:** I just tested this and it works. Changed the APN, put my iPhone SIM in, and it worked.

Comment: I hope this lasts, but can't imagine Apple would go to all the trouble to warn people to pick a carrier if it were this simple. Perhaps that warning is for 4G issues or in case the carriers lock this down somehow?